# How to Autosize WPF datagrid height to fill tag page

Tags: wpf, datagrid, tabs

I need to have my DataGrid height auto-expand to meet the height of the tab page it is in.  Currently, the DataGrid's height only expands to meet the height of all rows it has data for.

Here is an example of it current appearance:
I need the DataGrid to expand to the lower horizonal mark in the example:

[image: Example Appearance]

Here is my XAML for the UserControl with the DataGrid:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Nexidia.Esi.ManagementConsole.Views.RamActivesControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Nexidia.Esi.ManagementConsole.Views.Converters"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid Background="#FFF1F1F1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel x:Name="RamControlsPanel" Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="4 4 0 4">
            <Button Content="Refresh" Width="60" Margin="0 0 4 0" Click="ButtonRefresh_OnClick" />
            <Button Content="New..." Width="60"  Margin="0 0 4 0" Click="ButtonNew_OnClick" />
        </StackPanel>
        <DataGrid x:Name="RamActivesDataGrid"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding RamActives}"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  SelectionMode="Single"
                  CanUserAddRows="False"
                  CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                  CanUserResizeRows="False"
                  RowHeaderWidth="0"
                  SelectionUnit="FullRow">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <converters:ListToStringConverter x:Key="ListToString" />
            </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Created" Width="135" Binding="{Binding CreatedTimeUtc}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Modified" Width="135" Binding="{Binding ModifiedTimeUtc}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Originator" Width="135" Binding="{Binding Originator}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Profiles with access" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=RestrictedAccessInstanceProfiles, Converter={StaticResource ListToString}}" />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Actions" Width="90" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Width="15" Cursor="Hand" MouseDown="ImageEdit_OnMouseDown" ToolTip="Edit Instance">
                                    <Image.Source>
                                        <BitmapImage UriSource="../Icons/edit.png" />
                                    </Image.Source>
                                </Image>
                                <Image Margin="10 0 0 0" Width="15" Cursor="Hand" MouseDown="ImageStop_OnMouseDown" ToolTip="Stop Instance">
                                    <Image.Source>
                                        <BitmapImage UriSource="../Icons/remove.png" />
                                    </Image.Source>
                                </Image>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Instance Id" Width="115" Binding="{Binding InstanceId}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Parent Instance Id" Width="115" Binding="{Binding ParentInstanceId}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Original Instance Id" Width="115" Binding="{Binding OriginalInstanceId}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**EDIT: Added below code snippet to help diagnose the cause.**

Here is my XAML for my Tabs Container Control housing the UserControl with the DataGrid:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Nexidia.Esi.ManagementConsole.Views.RamTabsContainerControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:Nexidia.Esi.ManagementConsole.Views"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

<Grid Background="#FFF1F1F1">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel x:Name="RamControlsPanel" Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 10 0 10" >
            <RadioButton x:Name="DateUtc" GroupName="datesStyle"  Content="Display dates in UTC" IsChecked="True" Margin="6 0 0 0"/>
            <RadioButton x:Name="DateLocal" GroupName="datesStyle" Content="Display dates in local times" Margin="20 0 0 0"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="OptionsTabControl" Grid.Row="0" Padding="6">
            <TabItem Header="Active Instances" x:Name="RamActivesTabOption">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Views:RamActivesControl x:Name="RamActives" />
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="History" x:Name="RamHistoriesTabOption">
                <Views:RamHistoriesControl x:Name="RamHistories" />
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: That is how `DataGrid` is designed

Comment: By default, the DataGrid would stretch to fill the available space. Please create a blank project and start to add the TabControl and children (configured like in your original code) to the project. Then start to add its ancestors towards the root until you are able to reproduce the unwanted layout behavior. Then update your question with this minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code snippets are not enough to diagnose the cause.
I am almost 100% sure that the problem is not in the DataGrid, but in the overall layout. If you check the height value of your UserControl `RamActivesControl` at runtime, you will notice that the value of its ActualHeight property is limited and is not equal to the entire available space. And then this restriction applies to the child DataGrid. It is highly likely that a StackPanel is used somewhere higher in the layout.

Comment: You diagnosed it correctly, EldHash.  Thanks so much!
(I added the Tabs Container Control XAML to further the example).

I removed the overall StackPanel in the Tabs Container Control XAML and that fixed it.
I did not know the <Grid> functions as its own "StackPanel"

Comment: @BruceBWilson A StackPanel always tries to shrink its child elements to the minimum size sufficient in the direction of its orientation. This is a bit like a Grid in which all rows are sized "Auto". You set a row in the Grid with size "*", but the outer StackPanel actually turned it into size "Auto". Therefore, the DataGrid was compressed to the minimum sufficient size. Is everything working for you currently?

Comment: Yes, I've got it all working now, thanks.  I was missing the core concepts that you just outlined.